# how to access homedir by root user

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sudo

I want to access `root` user's home directory `/root/`. However following commands dont lead me to the root directory.

> sudo -s
>
> cd ~

It leads to the home dir of regular user. How to access `/root` when using `sudo -s` to login as `root`. I am using `bash4` on `ubuntu12.04`.

Comment: try `sudo su`. Not sure what is the difference

Comment: same question on unix&linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46904/4667

Answer (score 1):

Try `cd /root`.

`~` is normally just a shorthand for the home directory, so if you are the regular user `person` then `cd ~` is the same as `cd /home/person`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
sudo -i
```

To start in interactive session as root, which is treated as a login shell. This will set the HOME environment variable appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -s
```

lets you to execute a command as *another user* ([sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo))

Basically, you are still logged in with your *regular user* but that one single command after -s is executed by *another user* (root in your case).

```
$sudo -s ls -l    // you are root on this line
$cd ~             // you are regular user on this line
```

This is the reason why you are getting redirected into the home of your *regular user*.

Doing such things in general is a bad idea, this is why Ubuntu disabled such forms of root login.

If you could give us a hint what do you want to achieve, somebody may figure out how to solve that without substituting your *regular user* shell with a *root* shell.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo su - root`

su will switch the user

However you need to specify the user you wish to switch too e.g. - root

Root will be used as default if you don't specify the user